# How to retrieve first and last day of the previous month in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, datediff

I am looking to create a get the first and last date of the previous month so I can do a WHERE clause with a between statement. It'll look something like this

```
WHERE 
FirstSold_Date BETWEEN first_day_previous_month AND last_day_previous_month
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE FirstSold_Date BETWEEN date_trunc(date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 month), month) AND last_day(date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 month), month)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend `between` for this.  Instead:

```
WHERE FirstSold_Date >= date_add(date_trunc(current_date, month), interval -1 month) and
      FirstSold_Date < date_trunc(current_date, month)
```

The advantage of this approach is that the same logic works for `timestamp`s and `datetime`s as well.  Looking at the *last date* causes problems when times are involved.

Comment: I liked this but wht not between?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below

```
where date_trunc(FirstSold_Date, month) = date_trunc(date_sub(current_date, interval 1 month), month)
```